# flickers when ng-repeat, bootstrap modal, position fixed used in Firefox

Tags: firefox, modal-dialog, fixed, flicker, angularjs-ng-repeat

FIRST OF ALL, THIS ISSUE DOES NOT HAPPEN IN CHROME OR IE. ONLY IN FIREFOX.

I have a table filled by ng-repeat.

Out of the table I have a ui-bootstrap modal popup and a div with fixed position.

When I close/dismiss the popup by clicking away or pressing Esc button, if I click away once more before the popup completely disappears, the fixed positioned div flickers.

Here is a plunker that mimics the problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Lw9Emlfj7Zayi08agSNd?p=preview

To replicate my problem, use firefox, open any of the three popup, and press Esc or click away to close the popup. While the popup is disappearing, click elsewhere again, and pay attention to the fixed div on top that will flicker.

AGAIN, THIS ISSUE DOES NOT HAPPEN IN CHROME OR IE. ONLY IN FIREFOX.

Thanks in advance.

```
<div style="position:fixed" >
  Fixed Area
</div>
<br>
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>

    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
        <td>{{item.value1}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value2}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value3}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value4}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value5}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value6}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value7}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value8}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value9}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value10}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value11}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value12}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value13}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value14}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value15}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```